Auto List Members Toggle OFF and ON Keyboard Shortcut?
Is it possible to Assign a Shortcut to toggle Auto List Members for All Languages ON and OFF?
If All Languages is not possible, C# Auto List Members will suffice.
I looked at edit.toggleCompletionMode in the KeyBoard shortcuts but that doesn't target Auto List Members.
Perhaps there is an Extension that can do this?


If you really want this shortcut, I suggest you report this feature request to VS Developer Community, where there are many VS developers who may be able to help you. (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest)
It is important to note that if there are enough users submitting requests for this feature, Microsoft may process the feature request in this area, and if there are not many users submitting the feature request, Microsoft may not consider this aspect of the feature.
